# Can't read and print a set of bytes as Strings using RandomAcessFile

Tags: java

I am simulating a hashing data structure using `RandomAccessFile`. I already wrote all I wanted to write in my file but I can't get to read and print a set of bytes for my file as strings. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RandomAccessFile rand = ... // Your RandomAccessFile instance.

rand.seek(0);

for (long i = 0; i < rand.length(); i++) 
{
    byte b = rand.readByte();
    System.out.print((char)b);
}
```

Comment: i tried that and im still getting numbers when i run the program instead of letters

Comment: @Sabaspro if there is no letters, no letter will be printed.

Comment: for examples in this case, in my file i am reading "alejandro" and i get the ascii or unicode values i think, what i get is: 6510810110697110100114111